# Debug how vim calls makeprg

Tags: filetype-python, makeprg, vim8

I'm trying to set up pylint to work with `:make` command in Vim 8.2.

I've set `:compiler pylint` but running `:make` gives me pylint's help message, so some arguments seem to be passed incorrectly.

`:set makeprg?` is

```
makeprg=pylint --output-format=text --msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}: [{symbol}] {msg}" --reports=no
```

I've tried to run this command directly in the terminal (appending the filename) and it worked -- output was the list of errors, not help message.

Unfortunately, I don't see which exact command vim is trying to execute. Any hints on what I did wrong or how to debug it?

I'd like to stick to vim's default functionality as much as possible and not use any plugins for this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Note that `:make` takes arguments; perhaps you need to run `:make %`? For debugging, either see `:help :debug` or `:help 'verbose'`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ah yes, you're right! Somehow I was sure it's appended automatically

Comment: Np; if that solved your problem, feel free to self-answer! That's encouraged when you have a solution (and I certainly don't *need* the rep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to debug it?

You can use the [`:verbose`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Averbose) command to increase verbosity of a specific command.

In this particular case, [you need verbosity level above 3 to see the actual shell command executed by Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/misc2.c#L3145,L3149), so this should work:

```
:4verbose make
Calling shell to execute: "pylint --output-format=text --msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}: [{symbol}] {msg}" --reports=no  2>&1| tee /tmp/abcde12/3"
```

> Any hints on what I did wrong?

As [@D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) pointed out, you're missing the name of the current file in the execution of the command. You can either fix it by passing it to the `:make` command, with `:make %`, or you can actually incorporate the `%` into `makeprg` itself, since it will expand `%` before running the command:

```
:let &makeprg = 'pylint --output-format=text --msg-template="{path}:{line}:{column}:{C}: [{symbol}] {msg}" --reports=no %'
```

Note the `%` at the end of the command-line. If you incorporate `%` into `makeprg`, then simply running `:make` will work to run pylint on your current file.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Thanks to @d-ben-knoble)

`makeprg` does not include filename, so

```
:make %
```

should be used to lint the current file